# Ошибка при работе с volatile

Tags: java, многопоточность, volatile

Как мне известно `volatile` обеспечивает атомарность. И немного не могу понять почему `count` выдает разные значения. Знаю, что инкремент является не атомарным и поэтому написал так.

```
public class Main{
    public static volatile int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                    count = count - 1;
                }
            }
        });

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
                    count = count + 1;
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();
        thread1.start();

        thread.join();
        thread1.join();

        System.out.println(count);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`volatile` не обеспечивает атомарность. Данное ключевое слово заявляет, что каждая отдельная операция записи или чтения будет видна другим потокам. `volatile` по большей части помогает компилятору понять, что с этой переменной надо работать аккуратнее, например предотвращать reordering операций.

Инкремент `count++` выполняет 3 отдельные операции чтения, сложения, записи:

```
count = count + 1
```

Поэтому допустима ситуация (T1 и T2 - потоки):

- T1: Чтение count (count == 0)
- T2: Чтение count (count == 0)
- T1: Запись count + 1 (count == 1)
- T2: Запись count + 1 (count == 1) -- T2 в контексте хранит, что count == 0, хотя T1 уже произвёл запись
- T2: Чтение count (count == 1)

Для атомарности используйте `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: А, понял, спасибо. Я просто думал, что valotile помогает избежать ошибок во время этих 3 операций и что помогает при записи  и чтении long и double(если не ошибаюсь, то там происходит это в два подхода по 32 бита). Кстати, что лучше - использовать синхроницаю или Attomic?(именно в этой ситации  и подобных)

Comment: Вместо спасибо лучше отметьте ответ верным) для инкремента переменных лучше использовать специальные атомарные классы

Comment: @Alex atomic почти всегда лучше синхронизации, просто он сильно ограничен, не получится атомарно большую критическую секцию выполнить.

Comment: @АндрейГородецкий Отметил, я просто тут недавно, только узнал об этой функции))